# ssh login as user and change to root, without sudo

Tags: go

I have the following task for my golang code:

- The command has to be run as root user on the server remotely in bash and the command output has to be fetched in a variable.
- Logging over ssh as root is disabled.
- sudo on the server is disabled, so I have to use 'su -' and type password
- since I want to make it as automated as possible in bash, the password has to be stored inside the command

Here are the workflow actions:

1. Login via SSH (as unprivileged user) to remote host
2. Elevate to privileged 'root' user --> su -
3. Type the root password
4. run the command which root can execute
5. get to output to string on localhost and do some actions

I have Googled for days, but it seems that I cannot find a solution for this.
Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Having `sudo` disabled and requiring use of `su` is an insecure and potentially dangerous configuration. Contact the server administrator or IT security immediately to report the problem. Anyway, remember that you can just provide the command you want to run as an argument to `su` (or `sudo`).

Comment: Rather than trying to switch to root, elevate the logged in user to have root privileges. Add the user to sudoers file. SSH and then use `sudo <command to run>`.

Comment: I could not agree more with Michael Hampton. A software external to the system *becoming* root and therefor would be able to execute arbitrary commands which not only could wreak havoc, but which stores the root password somewhere is a galaxy sized "No No" in any IT environment.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is concerning interacting with the command after it has been executing.

It is quite easy to use `exec.Command` for non-interactive commands.

I would recommend using `Expect` for interaction, or the Golang equivalent located [here](https://github.com/ThomasRooney/gexpect).